# JS default argument value from variable: why must identifier be different?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment

Assigning a default value using a variable with the same name throw a reference error:

```
var a = 'adef';
var x = (a=a) => console.log(a);
x();
=> "ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

But this is fine:

```
var other = 'otherdef';
var x = (a=other) => console.log(a);
x();
=> "otherdef"
```

My assumption was that the value of `a` in the outer scope would be assigned to the new scope.

I have tried using `const` instead of `var`, and `class`/`function` instead of an arrow-function, but the result is always the same (tested in chrome 63 and node 6).

I have a feeling the issue is that `a` is 'hoisted' during assignment and so the assignment is referring to the new 'a' (which exists but is undefined)...

Comment: Yes, the `a` is indeed [hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572) in the [parameter scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44896829/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this behavior is to allow a parameter to be default-initialized to the value of another parameter, e.g:

```
var a = 2;
var x = (a, b = a) => console.log(a, b);
x(42); // 42 42
```

Making the special case `a = a` work differently *could* be done but that would make it harder to refactor functions that use this behavior (you wouldn't be able to rename the parameter `a` without also renaming the variable that it depends on).