# Why does redeclaring an identifier in a function, mask a parameter of the same name?

Tags: javascript

**TLDR:** Why are function parameters not treated as `var` declarations?

Using `var`, redeclaring a variable declared using `var` has no effect. The original declaration remains in effect.

However, using `var` in this way will mask a parameter of the same name.

Why is the language designed like this?

In the following, variable `var bar` is treated as a new declaration and not a redeclaration of parameter `bar`.

```js
function foo(bar = 0, bam = () => bar) {
  var bar = 1
  return bam()
}
console.log(foo()) // 0
```

Is it designed like this because arguments and local variables are semantically fundamentally different, and fall into two categories?

I might have expected parameters to be treated like `var` declarations, but they aren't. They appear to be in their own "box" on the scope chain.

So the scope chain of a function looks like this:

```
function body >> parameter list >> outer function body >> outer parameter list >> ... global scope
```

Comment: This is the kind of counter-intuitive behaviours that recent language additions have been addressing. If you declare variables with `let` you get `SyntaxError: redeclaration of formal parameter bar`

Comment: It looks like ES2015 introduced this.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález there is no issue there, it's the expected behaviour. You are re-initialising a binding for the current scope in that case. You'd get the same if you had `var foo; let foo;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are arguments and local variables semantically fundamentally different, and fall into two categories?

No, not really. In fact, in many cases they are indistinguishable, creating variables in the same scope - just not here in the example you gave.

> I might have expected parameters to be treated like `var` declarations, but they aren't. They appear to be in their own "box" on the scope chain.

Yes. That's because you are using default initialisers in your parameter declaration, which gives the parameters their own scope, and the function body scope is a child of that. Still, `var`s are getting declared in that body scope (not getting hoisted).

It might be fitting to say that parameters are treated like `let` declarations since ES6, except where they need to be treated as `var` declarations to preserve backwards compatibility (allowing re-declarations). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331886/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693246/1048572) for details.

Comment: OK, so this behavior is an artifact of the addition of default arguments to the language?

Comment: @BenAston I wouldn't say "artifact", it seems deliberate. Yes, before the addition of the parameter defaults the scopes could not be distinguished at all. Now since we have them, `let` semantics with TDZ and everything were chosen for the initialisation of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `variable hoisting` and `clouser` in javascript states that variables remembers enviornment in which they are created.

Now lets have a look in your example line by line

```
function foo(bar = 0, bam = () => bar) { // here bar 0, and function `bam` will remember bar value as 0 whenever it gets called
```

And when you are reassigning `bar` to `1` in function `foo`, function `bam` will not update it. As both function have different scopes.

So as per the javascript concept, this is correct and desired behaviour.

Update:

```
function foo(bar = 0, bam = () => bar) {
   bar = 1
   return bam()
}
console.log(foo()) // 1
```

Comment: The arrow function's closure will not remember the value of `bam`, but maintain a (indirect) reference to the actual parameter.

Comment: The question is *why* they have different scopes. The scoping with parameters is a bit unintuitive, so it's not clear the reason `bam` has different scope to `foo`

Comment: Agreed but for that you are redeclaring `bar` in your function. which will have local scope. If you don't declare it, then it will maintain reference. See my updated example