# How does closure work in function expressions passed as parameters?

Tags: javascript, closures

A thing about `closure`. 
In these two snippets below I'm passing a function expression as a callback.

(In the first snippet) When calling back the function expression, I expect to see the anonymous function to close over `def`, but when I call `second()` instead of looking inside its "closure" for the variable `first` (where `first` is `updatedValue`), search and find `first` in the global variable environment, where first has the value `oldValue`.

```
function def(first="oldValue" , second=function(){
         return first;
}){
        var first="updatedValue";
        console.log('inside',first);
        console.log('function',second());
}


//OUTPUT: 
inside updatedValue
function oldValue
```

On the other hand, if you don't declare `first` inside def, it `second()` console log `updatedValue`

```
function def(first="oldValue" , second=function(){
         return first;
}){
        first="updatedValue";           // NOTE: removed the `var` here
        console.log('inside',first);
        console.log('function',second());
}
//OUTPUT:
inside updatedValue
function updatedValue
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: You're not *passing the closure as a parameter*. You are defining a default initialiser for the parameter that gets used when nothing is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quoted from the ES specs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896829/scope-of-default-function-parameters-in-javascript), using a default parameter creates a new scope in which the default parameters reside, then another scope in which the function body resides. That means that `first` refers to the variable in the enclosing default parameter scope, while `var first` shadows it in the functions scope.

Your code basically is the same as:

```
function def(_first, _second) {
  // Scope of the default parameters
  let first = _first ?? "default";
  let second = _second ?? function(){
     return first;
  };
  (function() {
     // The functions scope          
     var first = "updatedValue"; // scoped here
     console.log('inside',first);
    console.log('function',second());
  })();
}
```

Comment: Hi @JonasWilms , could you please also explain why 2 separate scopes are created for the 2 parameters with default values, apart from the function body scope ? In all the examples in the link you shared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896829/scope-of-default-function-parameters-in-javascript, only 1 scope is created for all parameters with default values. Also in this answer of yours parameters are declared using var but in the link you provided parameters are declared using let after de-sugaring, so how is var or let determined ?

Comment: @DhirenPunjabi this answer is slightly incorrect, technically there is only one environment record in which the default parameters are evaluated, though as parameters are only bound after being evaluated, later parameters are not visible in the evaluation of the default expression (c.f. https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation 28.f)

Comment: So yeah, using one invoked function with let is a more accurate syntactic sugar.

Comment: As per this answer of yours to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301703/why-is-there-still-a-duplicate-error-even-when-i-declare-the-variable-in-2-diffe , the parameter names also exist in the scope of the function body and if the parameters are declared by let (as per your above reply to my comment) then it might cause a redeclaration error. So it looks like parameters are declared with var by default and not let, for every javascript function. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @DhirenPunjabi parameters and let and const variables are three entirely different things with varying semantics, all of which can be described by environment records and bindings.