# declaring a variable twice in IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I came through this fun quiz on the internet.

```
console.log((function(x, f = (() => x)){
  var x;
  var y = x;
  x = 2;
  return [x, y, f()]
})(1))
```

and the choices were:

1. [2,1,1]
2. [2, undefined, 1]
3. [2, 1, 2]
4. [2, undefined, 2]

I picked solution 2 TBH, basing that on that x has been redefined, y was declared and defined with no value, and that f has a different scope hence getting the global x memory spot than function x memory spot.

However, I tried it in [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/cakiheqita/1/edit?js,console)

and I found it was solution 1, while I was not sure why that happened I messed with the function body and I removed `var x` from the function body, I found that the response changed to #3 which makes sense as x value changed and hence it showed x and f as 2 and y as 1 which was declared globally.

but still I can't get why it shows 1 instead of undefined.

Comment: I find the best way to figure these things out is to step through them line by line with a debugger, and/or print out the values after each line.

Comment: `var x;` doesn't define a new variable within the function scope, where `var x = somevalue;` would

Comment: @alex it does. ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I see, would have expected x to be undefined then, implicitly copy the function formal value looks really odd to me.

Comment: @alex it has its reasons.

Comment: I'm glad this question was asked :)

Comment: Related: [Scope of Default function parameters in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44896829/1048572)

Comment: I first read "declaring a variable twice in LIFE". Seems doable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> but still I can't get why it shows 1 instead of undefined.

It's not just you. This is a deep, dark part of the specification. :-)

The key here is that there are two `x`s. Yes, really. There's the *parameter* `x`, and there's the *variable* `x`.

A parameter list containing *expressions* (like `f`'s default value) has its *own scope* separate from the function body's scope. But prior to parameter lists possibly having expressions, having `var x` within a function with an `x` parameter had no effect (`x` was still the parameter, with the parameter's value). So to preserve that, when there's a parameter list with expressions in it, a separate variable is created and the value of the parameter is **copied** to the variable at the beginning of the function body. Which is the reason for this <s>seemingly-odd</s> *(no, not just seemingly)* odd behavior. (If you're the kind who likes to dive into the spec, this copying is Step 28 of [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation).)

Since `f`'s default value, `() => x`, is created within the parameter list scope, it refers to the *parameter* `x`, not the var.

So the first solution, `[2, 1, 1]` is correct, because:

- `2` was assigned to the var `x` in the function body. So at the end of the function, the var `x` is `2`.
- `1` was assigned to `y` from the var `x` before `x` got the value `2`, so at the end of the function, `y` is `1`.
- The *parameter* `x`'s value has never changed, so `f()` results in `1` at the end of the function

It's *as though* the code were written like this instead (I've removed unnecessary parens and added missing semicolons):

```js
console.log(function(param_x, f = () => param_x) {
  var var_x = param_x;
  var y = var_x;
  var_x = 2;
  return [var_x, y, f()];
}(1));
```

> ...I removed var x from the function body, I found that the response changed to #3...

#3 is `[2, 1, 2]`. That's correct, because when you remove the `var x` from the function, there's only one `x`, the parameter (inherited by the function body from the parmeter list). So assigning `2` to `x` changes the parameter's value, which `f` returns.

Taking the earier example with `param_x` and `var_x`, here's what it looks like if you remove the `var x;` from it:

```js
console.log(function(param_x, f = () => param_x) {
  var y = param_x;
  param_x = 2;
  return [param_x, y, f()];
}(1));
```

---

Here's an annotated description of the original code (with the extraneous parentheses removed and missing semicolons added):

```
//                   /---- the parameter "x"
//                   v  vvvvvvvvvvv--- the parameter "f" with a default value
console.log(function(x, f = () => x) {
  var x;      // <=== the *variable* x, which gets its initial value from the
              //      parameter x
  var y = x;  // <=== sets y to 1 (x's current value)
  x = 2;      // <=== changes the *variable* x's value to 2
  //      +---------- 2, because this is the *variable* x
  //      |  +------- 1, because this is the variable y
  //      |  |   +--- 1, because f is () => x, but that x is the *parameter* x,
  //      |  |   |       whose value is still 1
  //      v  v  vvv
  return [x, y, f()];
}(1));
```

---

Final note regarding your title:

> declaring a variable twice in IIFE

The *variable* is only declared once. The other thing is a parameter, not a variable. The distinction is rarely important...this being one of those rare times. :-)

Comment: This is now in my list of "new weird things about JavaScript" alongside the semantics of (not yet really standard) instance property initialization expressions in `class` declarations.

Comment: @Pointy - Oh, this is *much* weirder than field declarations. :-D

Comment: Well field declarations are jarring to me because `this` is the instance, not the `this` of the surrounding scope as with object initializers. I guess it's not really "weird" if you think of `class` declarations as being something akin to macro expansion.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah. I think of them as code that's relocated to the beginning of the constructor (just after the `super` call if it's a subclass). That's what Java does with instance field initializers and instance initialization blocks (and they're *literally* copied to the beginning of *each* constructor in Java; thankfully in JavaScript we just have the one). JavaScript took effectively the same approach.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is a great explanation, it is really weird that var x is assigned directly from the parameter x although there is no obvious assignments, thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part of that code is that the `=>` function is created as part of a default parameter value expression. In parameter default value expressions, the scope includes the parameters declared to the left, which in this case includes the parameter `x`.  Thus for that reason the `x` in the `=>` function is in fact the first parameter.

The function is called with just one parameter, `1`, so when the `=>` function is called that's what it returns, giving `[2, 1, 1]`.

The `var x` declaration, as Mr Crowder points out, has the (somewhat weird, at least to me) effect of making a *new* `x` in the function scope, into which is copied the value of the *parameter* `x`. Without it, there's only the one (the parameter).

Comment: @JonasWilms you're right; the `var` declaration must ... do *something* but it doesn't seem obvious to me what that is. It's as if the `var` declaration creates a new `x` in the function scope, but it clearly gets the value of the *parameter* `x` anyway (which I'd expect), leaving the parameter apparently in its own scope.

Comment: I guess the values are somewhat copied from the default initializers scope to the bodies scope. Im already digging into the spec

Comment: It makes sense. As noted in the spec: `NOTE: A separate Environment Record is needed to ensure that closures created by expressions in the
formal parameter list do not have visibility of declarations in the function body.` thats reasonable.

Comment: @Pointy - It's a very deep, dark part of the spec. :-)